# Realm crash when try [RLMRealm defaultRealm]

Tags: cocoapods, realm, tvos

I added Realm pod to my tvos project. However it crash when I just try:

```
[RLMRealm defaultRealm]
```

It crash in simulator and device. I created a tvos empty project, added the Realms pod and it works. So I guess it's something related with the current project.

If the problem appear in the line 361 of `RLMRealm` file.

```
try {
      realm->_realm = [self openSharedRealm:config error:error];
}

catch (SchemaMismatchException const& exception) {
     if (configuration.deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded) {
          BOOL success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:configuration.fileURL error:nil];
          if (success) {
               realm->_realm = [self openSharedRealm:config error:error];
          } else {
                RLMSetErrorOrThrow(RLMMakeError(RLMException(exception)), error);
                return nil;
          }
     } else {
          RLMSetErrorOrThrow(RLMMakeError(RLMException(exception)), error);
          return nil;
     }
}
```

It executes `RLMSetErrorOrThrow(RLMMakeError(RLMException(exception)), error);` but the error is nil and it doesn't give me any extra information

Comment: There should be an exception logged in the console, what does it say?

Comment: Nothing. I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: I removed Realm pod and added the Realm xcodeproj as target dependency. It works now. I hope it helps somebody